# Checking a session variable in a PHP class

Tags: php, oop, session

At the top of my index page a set a session using:

```
$_SESSION['language'] = 'english';
```

and when I echo $_SESSION['language'] it echoes 'english', However the session value is not readable inside a PHP class, why is that?

Comment: Might help to see more code. Otherwise it will be just speculation.

Comment: did you use `session_start()` everywhere you use the session?

Comment: Sounds like a lack of `session_start()` somewhere.

Comment: session_start() was lacking, Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You must call `session_start()` before you have access to the `$_SESSION` super global

[PHP session_start() docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php)