# Sessions inside PHP classes

Tags: php, oop, session

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Checking a session variable in a PHP class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10654809/checking-a-session-variable-in-a-php-class)

```
public function __construct(){
        $this->languages     = get_option('test_trans');
        $this->default_lang  = $this->default_language();
        $this->taxonomies   = get_taxonomies(array(),'names');

        add_action('init', array($this, 'webchanics_e_translations_session_master'), 1);
        session_start();
        $this->current_language = $_SESSION['language'];

    }


    function webchanics_e_translations_session_master(){    
        if(!$this->languages){
            unset($_SESSION['language']);
        }else{
            $check_lang_by_session = $this->check_language($_SESSION['language']);
            if(!$check_lang_by_session){
                $_SESSION['language'] = $this->default_lang;
            }

            $check_lang_by_url = $this->check_language($_GET['lang']);
            if($check_lang_by_url){
                $_SESSION['language']=$_GET['lang'];
            }
        }  
    }
```

This code sets a session based on some conditions, and the calls the value stroed in this session. Outside the class, the new value of the session is available instantly, but inside the class the value of $this->current_language remains the old one until I refresh the page again. What's the explanation of this? and how to make the value inside the class to change instantly?

Comment: That's wrong it it's not a duplication

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing an assignment by value, not by reference.
Do it with reference: `$this->current_language = &$_SESSION['language'];`

Comment: It works very well my friend: https://gist.github.com/2726195

Comment: I'd suggest passing the session as an argument: `webchanics_e_translations_session_master($session)`. Which is cleaner anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning the **value** of `$_SESSION['language']` to `$this->current_language`, meaning when you access `$this->current_language`, you are making PHP do a copy of `$_SESSION['language']` (PHP only copies when it needs to), not a reference to the same memory location.

You could instead deal with `$this->current_language`, and at the end of your block, sync it back to `$_SESSION['language']` or omit the `$this->current_language` altogether and just access the `$_SESSION`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to store the reference, not only the value.

```
$this->current_language = &$_SESSION['language'];
```

Please see this [article about PHP references](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.php) on PHP.net.